# Is the PHP Intl extension thread safe? 

Tags: php, localization, thread-safety, locale, php-extension

I've been reading about locales in PHP and it seems `setlocale()` has problems with threads. (I'm not too familiar with threads - the docs mention it is not thread safe)

I'd like to give my project the ability to deal with certain number formats and the Intl extension seems interesting.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

Should I expect the same problems that `setlocale()` has using the Intl extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I was curious about this myself as well, so I devised a test.

First I tested `setlocale()` with these two files:

```
<?php
# locale1.php
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );

date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Amsterdam' );
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'dutch_nld' ); // awkward Windows locale string

sleep( 10 ); // let's sleep for a bit here

echo strftime( '%A, %B %d, %Y %X %Z', time() );
```

and

```
<?php
# locale2.php
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );

date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Los_Angeles' );
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'english_usa' ); // awkward Windows locale string

echo strftime( '%A, %B %d, %Y %X %Z', time() );
```

Then I executed them in two seperate tabs. First `locale1.php`, that sleeps for 10 seconds after setting the locale, giving us time to execute `locale2.php` in the meanwhile.

<strike>To my surprise `locale2.php` isn't even allowed to change the locale correctly. It appears `sleep( 10 )` in `locale1.php` hijacks the Apache/PHP process in such a way that it doesn't allow `locale2.php` to alter the locale in the meanwhile. It *does* however echo the date in the meanwhile of course, just not localized as you'd expect.</strike>

**Edit:** sorry, scrap that. It appears `locale2.php` *does* change the locale and `locale1.php` then prints the English date in stead of Dutch after sleeping. So that *does* appear to be in accordance with what is expected behavior from `setlocale()`.
**/Edit**

Then, I tested `IntlDateFormatter` with these two files:

```
<?php
# locale1.php
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );

$dateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'nl_NL',
     IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
     IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
     'Europe/Amsterdam'
);

sleep( 10 ); // let's sleep for a bit here

echo $dateFormatter->format( time() );
```

and

```
<?php
# locale2.php
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );

$dateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US',
     IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
     IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
     'America/Los_Angeles'
);

echo $dateFormatter->format( time() );
```

and then executed them again in two separate tabs, the same way as with the first set of files. This *does* give the expected results: while `locale1.php` is sleeping `locale2.php` nicely prints a date in American-English according to American rules, after which `locale1.php` nicely prints a date in Dutch according to Dutch rules.

So, concluding, it appears `Intl` is safe from that `setlocale` problem.

But also mind [Hyunmin Kim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11025442/165154) answer of course. I couldn't comment on that, due to lack of experience with using `Intl`. I only recently discovered `Intl`.

Comment: Interesting test - I haven't experimented with locales yet so this is new territory for me. What would the difference be between the `setlocale` and `Intl` approach?

Comment: Well, for one thing, `Intl` appears to be safer and thus more reliable in this regard. The thread problem with `setlocale` that you mentioned, is exactly this problem I demonstrated: you can never be sure that another thread (meaning another php script) isn't changing the locale while you were just about to print a nice localized date (or anything else that depends on `setlocale`) of your own.

Answer (score 2):

The Intl extension is safe and very useful if you're working not working inside a framework.

For example, if you're using Symfony2, your programs will most likely crash when using Forms and Validators.

Comment: My project is currently using the CodeIgniter framework -- do you know of any problems?