# how should i use setlocale? setting LC_NUMERIC only works sometimes

Tags: php, locale

My test script starts with setting some LC_values

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE.utf8");
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "sv_SE.utf8");
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.utf8");
```

Then i have a loop with a delay that store the result of 3/2:

```
$list = array();
$number = 3/2;

foreach(range(1, 1000) as $i)
{
    $key = (string) $number;

    if(!isset($list[$key]))
    {
        $list[$key] = 0;
    }

    $list[$key]++;

    usleep(100 * 1000);
}
```

And the result is:

```
Array
(
   [1.5] => 997
   [1,5] => 3
)
```

How come that 0.3% uses the "," instead of the "."?

Why doesn't LC_NUMERIC stay at the value i set?

How do i prevent this from happening?

also tried `strftime("%A")`, and got Swedish in only 6.6%

Above test was done with apache-2.2.22 and php-5.5.2.

if i run the test from bash/cli, I get expected results with 1000 "1.5" and 1000 "torsdag"

Comment: Are you running a multi-threaded server?

Comment: Apache is compiled with gentoos use-flag "threads", so i guess its is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to be running Apache in a threaded configuration, it is likely that some other thread resets the locale setting while your loop is running. The locale is a per-process setting, so using `setlocale` is generally not thread-safe. Many C libraries offer functions like `printf_l` with an additional `locale_t` parameter that can be used in threaded environments. Unfortunately, PHP doesn't offer similar functionality, AFAIK.

Other solutions:

- Switch to a non-threaded Apache configuration.
- Use locks and reset the locale around every locale-sensitive function call (usually unfeasible).
- Use an extension for localized output. The *Intl* extension seems to be thread-safe, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025186/is-the-php-intl-extension-thread-safe).

Answer (score 9):

set your locale as before but reset the decimal separator
There may be cases, you may need setting the locale anyway (even if i don’t know when this should be nessessary). If so, you can simply reset the decimal separator after setting the entired locale:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE");
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');
?>
```

This reset to ‘C’ locale for numerical values tell the operating system and PHP, that the C/C++ type of decimal separator has to be used which is defined as ‘.’ for programming languages. Now you get your locale based month names if you are using the ordinary PHP date() function but you get also correct calculated and converted numerical values (but you loose your locale known decimal sep char).